# Detect when watch is connected remotely or via bluetooth?

Tags: tizen

In my Android application I need to detect when my Tizen watch changes its connection state to phone:

1. Connected via Bluetooth (watch nearby)
2. Not connected at all (watch far)
3. **Connected remotely (watch far, but found Wifi or cellular data)**

Now the first and second one are quite easy with SAP, but how about the 3rd?

Comment: try: https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/connectivity/bluetooth/#prerequisites

you can use tizen framework, or you need to understand how in your android app you need to search for the BT device, good luck

Comment: The point is that watch is NOT connected by bluetooth but via Cellular!

Answer (score 0):

If you can check if the watch is not connected via Bluetooth using SAP, I think you could assume that the watch is connected via other network (Wi-Fi, Cellular) if you can communicate with the companion app in the watch.

I think there is no way of distinguish it directly.

Comment: Not connected via BT doesn't mean it's connected via Cellular: it can be turned off, or can work in Standalone mode, or can be discharged, or can be out-of-coverage.

Comment: And with SAP, you can't communicate with the watch, if it's not connected via Bluetooth. (Or at least, for me, in case watch is using LTE or Wifi (and not BT), SAP will not work.